# @if at Script TAG laravel

Tags: laravel

How to make this work, If statement not working at all

```
<script>
            @if(Session::has('messege'))
                var type="{{Session::get('alert-type','info')}}"
                switch(type){
                    case 'info':
                        toastr.info("{{ Session::get('messege') }}");
                        break;
                    case 'success':
                        toastr.success("{{ Session::get('messege') }}");
                    break;
                    case 'warning':
                        toastr.warning("{{ Session::get('messege') }}");
                    break;
                    case 'error':
                        toastr.error("{{ Session::get('messege') }}");
                    break;
                }
            @endif
    </script>
```

hope someone help me :)

Comment: Please provide more relevant information, for example where do you set the session, as well as any other relevant code

Comment: the Session is work, if there is no Script Tag

Comment: it only show code if there is no Script Tag

Comment: You don't set the session with Laravel.

Comment: You're trying to do a blade `@if` inside a script tag.  That wont work.

Comment: I follow a tutor video and he use @if in script tag and it work when I try it myself it wont work :(

Comment: @JohnHalsey Not exactly correct; `@{directive}` blade syntax can be used in a `<script>` tag as long as the *file* is still a `.blade.php` file, and not a `.js` file.

Comment: file extension is .blade.php

Comment: @riskiFerdi Update your code with the Controller code where `messege` (should that be `message`?) is being set into Laravel's session. Also, do a `{{ dd(Session::get("messege")) }}` and see if you get `true` or `false`

Comment: yes it actually messege

Comment: without using script tag ?

Comment: where should i put the {{ dd(Session::get("messege")) }}?

Comment: Put this line of code `{{ dd(Session::has("messege")) }}` somewhere in your `.blade.php` file; it will end execution of PHP and display `true` or `false`. Edit: Sorry, `Session::has()`, not `Session::get()`

Comment: it shows the info

Comment: i think if statement didnt executed

Comment: Well yeah, like I said, `dd()` stops execution of PHP code. It's is for debugging only; don't leave it in your code.

Comment: yeah i felt confuse, i will try to contact the tutor :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I see a few issues with the code you have provided.

So, you don't need to wrap the `@if` in a `<script>` tag. Laravel uses blade to parse it and execute it automatically.

Also you've spelt `message` wrong, this might be the reason for why the statement isn't executing at all. Double checking your syntax is a must when the code isn't working the way it's intended.

You can also set the variable in PHP, since you haven't provided any information to where the code is stored or what it's meant to show, don't use JavaScript when you can just use PHP. Set the variable `type` using the `$` symbol in PHP. Also by removing the `<script>` tags, you'll probably get a Laravel `exception` with more information as to why your code isn't working.

Try that, and if you're still having issues, post the Laravel error and I'll try to assist you again.

Comment: If you're new to Laravel, PHP or HTML, check our Laracasts.com

Comment: if there is no script tag?

Comment: He's trying to use `toastr`, which is a JS library, based on the existence of a session value from PHP. Removing the `<script>` makes no sense.

Comment: But you can't use @if within a `<script>` tag. It's the basics of Blade.

Comment: For reference, here is the code working and the console result. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQLeD.png

Answer (score 2):

Let's simplify this a little bit. Don't rely on PHP to execute JS code beyond what you need to rely on, and by that I mean convert `Session::get("messege")` into a JS variable and use that in your JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let message = "{{ Session::get('messege') }}";
    let type = "{{ Session::get('alert-type', 'info') }}";

    console.log(message, type);

    if(message){
        switch (type) {
            case "info":
                toastr.info(message);
                break;
            case "success":
                toastr.success(message);
                break;
            case "warning":
                toastr.warning(message);
                break;
            case "error":
                toastr.error(message);
                break;
        }
    }
</script>
```

As long as this `<script>` is in a `.blade.php` file, it'll translate `Session::get()` variables into JS, which you can then use in your JS code without relying on blade `@` syntax. Also, added in a `console.log()` statement so you can see what your variables contain, to confirm whether or not your code is executing. Also, open you Developer Tools (F12 in browsers) and view your Console tab; should tell you if anything is going wrong.